# What are the different values of "imagePullSecrets" and what does "regsecret" do?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

So I am trying to understand two parts:

1. What are the different types of values that can be put into "imagePullSecrets"?  What does each one do?
2. What in particular does "regsecret" value for "imagePullSecrets" do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`imagePullSecrets` is the parameter which has to be used to invoke authorization token, also known as a secret, that stores Docker credentials that are used for accessing Docker registry inside Kubernetes Pod configuration.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <SECRET_NAME> --docker-server=<FQDN_DOCKER_SERVER> --docker-username=<USER_NAME> --docker-password=<USER_PASSWORD> --docker-email=<USER_EMAIL>
```

I assume that `regsecret` equals `SECRET_NAME` from above command line example, which defines Kubernetes secret:

```
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
<SECRET_NAME>         kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         5d
```

Finally to revoke data from secret just needs `imagePullSecrets` to be included in the corresponded Pod configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: nginx-demo
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: nginx
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: nginx
      spec:
        hostNetwork: false
        containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: <FQDN_DOCKER_SERVER>
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <SECRET_NAME>
```

Related documentation links from official Kubernetes resource:

1. [Overview of Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/);
2. [Add ImagePullSecrets to a service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account);
3. [Using a Private Docker Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry)